# Mediation of Cubic Function using R Lavaan Package - Missing Results

Tags: r, multiple-regression, mediation, lavaan

I was trying to test for a mediation of a non-linear (cubic) relationship using the R lavaan package together with a syntax provided by some other authors doing a similar analysis. The loaded data contains index means for the 3 variables for 27 different images + high-order polynomials (2,3,4), all variables are continuous. I adjusted the provided script by the former authors in the following way (for me the mediator was better fit by a cubic function as well):

[image]

[image]

Although the script runs and provides me with some output, many values are said to be NA (not available I guess). Can anyone tell me what went wrong or does anyone know another easy way of running this type of analysis? Maybe it doesn't give me anything because the original cubic fit was not significant?

Many thanks in advance!